# Print data from another method, in a while loop in the main method only once

Tags: java, methods, printing, while-loop

The goal of this assignment is to read two numbers from the user, compute the distance between those numbers, then continue to ask the user for two numbers until they are equal, each time competing the distance, and the goal is to find the minimum distance between two numbers. We have to create a method that finds the minimum distance, and once the two numbers are equal, to print that minimum distance (only once). And the distance between the numbers that are equal does not count as a minimum distance. How do I do this? Thank you.

This is the code that I currently have.

```
double myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
while ( !(num1==num2)) {
      double dist;
      pairsMin(dist,myMin,num1,num2);
      // re-ask for user input of num1 and num2
      Min1 = pairsMin(dist,myMin,num1,num2);
}
System.out.print("\nThe minimum distance is: " + Min1 + "\n");
} // end of main method

public static double pairsMin( double dist, double myMin, double num1,double num2){
    dist = Math.abs(num1-num2);
    if ( dist<myMin) { // if dist is smaller than the minimum, then dist will be the new minimum
    myMin = dist;
    }
    return myMin;
    } // end of pairsMin method
```

Comment: The only things we've learned are for and while loops, if statements, System.in scanner, if,else, else if statements, and how to create new methods (only using void, double, int, String, boolean).

Comment: So what are you exactly missing? The user input in pairs min?

Comment: I started my main method with the user input (I didn't paste it here) and I also have it where the comment is on the 5th line.

Comment: So still the question what do you miss exactly? I suppose you miss an equality check in pairs min or a check if dist == 0 because like this your Min1 is always 0. Just return myMin if num1 == num2.

Comment: I thought if num1==num2, then the while loop will end, and after the while loop, I can't print myMin because you can't use anything declared in the while loop outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make minor changes to your logic. Try below

```
public static int pairsMin(int min, int num1, int num2) {
        int dist = 0;
        dist = Math.abs(num1 - num2);
        if (dist != 0 && dist < min) {
            min = dist;
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int mymin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
            num1 = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
            num2 = kb.nextInt();
            mymin = pairsMin(mymin, num1, num2);
        } while (!(num1 == num2));

        System.out.print("\nThe minimum distance is: " + mymin + "\n");
    } // end of main method
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I know have, using your suggestions, and it is working. I didn't think that my if statement in my while loop would execute because I thought once num1==num2, that the while loop would end, but it worked. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw5_pairs {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
double num1 = in.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
double num2 = in.nextDouble();
double Min1;
double myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double dist = Math.abs(num1-num2); 

while ( !(num1==num2)) {
    pairsMin(dist, num1, num2, myMin);
    System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
    num1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
    num2 = in.nextDouble();
    Min1 = pairsMin(dist,num1, num2, myMin);
    if (num1==num2) {
        System.out.print("\nThe minimum distance is: " + Min1 + "\n");
    }
}
}

public static double pairsMin( double dist, double num1, double num2, double        myMin){
    if ( dist<myMin) { // if dist is smaller than the minimum, then dist   will be the new minimum
         myMin = dist;
     }

     return myMin;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My new problem is that myMin is equalling the last distance before the numbers are equal instead of the actual minimum. e.g. say the first two numbers I enter are 1 and 2, and the next are 1 and 3, and then 1 and 1. It is saying my minimum is 2.0.
This is what I'm supposed to get for the assignment.

Enter number 1: 9

Enter number 2: 1

Enter number 1: 7

Enter number 2: 2

Enter number 1: 4

Enter number 2: 4

The minimum distance is:  5.0.

Enter number 1: 20

Enter number 2: 3

Enter number 1: 23

Enter number 2: 23

5.0 + 17.0 = 22.0

MY CODE:

```
double myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double Min1,Min2;

while ( !(num1==num2) ) {
    pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
    Min1 = pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
    System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
    num1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
    num2 = in.nextDouble();

    if (num1==num2) {
        System.out.print("\nThe minimum distance is: " + Min1 + "\n\n");
        myMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        num1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        num2 = in.nextDouble();
        while ( !(num1==num2)) {
        pairsMin( num1, num2, myMin);
        Min2 = pairsMin(num1,num2,myMin);
        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
        num1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
        num2 = in.nextDouble();

        if(num1==num2) {

            double totMin = Min1+Min2;
            System.out.print("\n" + Min1 + " + " + Min2 + " = " + totMin +  "\n");
        }
        }
    }
} // end while loop
} // end main method
public static double pairsMin( double num1, double num2, double myMin){
   double dist = Math.abs(num1-num2);
    if ( dist<myMin) { // if dist is smaller than the minimum, then dist will be the new minimum
         myMin = dist;
    }
    return myMin;
}
}
```